image file to array error due to data sheet limit
Using df.to_excel(filepath, index=False), I got the following errro: ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 1389080, 1 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384.
How can i get rid of that?
Do I have to modify my image?
